# React Native done button above keyboard

Tags: react-native

I want to add a "Done" button above the keyboard, that will hide the keyboard when clicked.

Here's an image demonstrating the desired button:

[image: An image demonstrating the desired button]

Is there any existing method or library for that? (I already found [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-done-button) but it doesn't work).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**For numeric and number-pad :**

and seems that you don't need any library
`returnKeyType='done' works with "number-pad" and "numeric" on v0.47.1`

**for normal keyboard you may look at this :**

https://github.com/ardaogulcan/react-native-keyboard-accessory

and

https://github.com/douglasjunior/react-native-keyboard-manager

**Github thread you need to take a look at :**

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1190

and

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/641

Hope it helps

Comment: I have problem with install react-native-keyboard-accessory. After test it, I will accept your answer :)

Comment: The Done button shows in hte keyboard, but it doesnt hide the keyboard. Please dvise.

Comment: This is false... the combo you proposed does not work on ios...

Answer (score 4):

You can use React-native's `KeyboardAvoidingView` Component as:

```js
<KeyboardAvoidingView keyboardVerticalOffset={50}>
  // View you want to be moved up when keyboard shows.
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

`keyboardVerticalOffset={50}` is the margin between the keyboard and the view, which will be the height of view or button you want. I hope that helps.

Edit: the best and most customizable way I think to do this, is listening to Keyboard events and changing the absolute position of the component you want above the keyboard, according to it.

```js
import { Keyboard } from "react-native";
            
componentDidMount () {
  this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', (event) => this.keyboardDidShow(event));
  this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', (event) => this.keyboardDidHide(event));
}
        
keyboardDidShow(event) {
  this.setState({keyboardShow:true,keyboardHeight:event.endCoordinates.height}) // <<You got the keyboard height 
}
        
keyboardDidHide(event) {
  this.setState({keyboardShow:false,keyboardHeight:0})
}
        
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
  this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
}
```

Now, to show it above the keyboard you can give style to your button component like this

```js
style={{
  position: "absolute",
  bottom: this.state.keyboardHeight + 20,
  right: 0
}}
```

And if you want to hide it (Done button) just condition the JSX with the `keyboardShow` state.

Comment: I already use KeyboardAvoidingView, But I want to make "Done" button above keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing my style of handling this case :

> **Code :**

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Platform, View, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
export default class StripAboveKeyboard extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { keyboardHeight: 0 }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', (event) => this.keyboardDidShow(event));
        this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', (event) => this.keyboardDidHide(event));
    }

    keyboardDidShow = (event) => this.setState({ keyboardShow: true, keyboardHeight: event.endCoordinates.height > 100 ? (Platform.OS == 'ios' ? event.endCoordinates.height : 0) : 0 })
    keyboardDidHide = (event) => this.setState({ keyboardShow: false, keyboardHeight: 0 })

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
    }

    render() {

        marginFromBottom = (this.state.keyboardHeight == 0) ? 0 : this.state.keyboardHeight

        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={style.parent}>
                    <View style={style.upper}>
                        <TextInput style={style.textInput}>User Name</TextInput>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ ...style.bottomParent, marginBottom: marginFromBottom }}>
                        <Text style={style.bottom}>Press me</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>)
    }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    parent: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
    },

    upper: {
        paddingTop: 44,
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        padding: 10,
        flex: 1,
        marginBottom: 10,
    },

    textInput: {
        height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1
    },

    bottomParent: {
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        width: '100%',
        height: 40,
    },

    bottom: {
        textAlignVertical: "center", textAlign: "center",
    }
})
```

> **Screenshots** :

**ANDROID & IOS**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is not a library or anything special. That is just a view that moves up with the keyboard.

Read this article - https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580#.gd37tn1wx

It shows you different ways to make elements respect the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Done button will not work for multiples line `TextInput`. To close keyboard you have to use

```
KeyboardAvoidingView
```

that will helpful to close it by touching outside of softkeyboard